# Django: creating linked tables with Foreign keys

Tags: database, django, sqlite, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have 3 tables in my SQLite database: User, Accounts, Passwords. The id of the Accounts and Passwords is a ForeignKey to User.id. The problem is that an instance of User doesn't have an id until it is saved (and django adds the Primary Field). This is how I am trying to do it, since the User.email should be unique then I should only get back one object but it isn't working. I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

tl;dr When I create a User, I also want an Accounts and Passwords table created for them, linked via a ForeignKey, id, which is also the PrimaryKey.

```
def adduser(request):
    u = User(email=request.POST['email'], username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    a = Accounts()
    u.save()
    u = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
    a.id = u.id
    a.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much closer to what you want.

```
def adduser(request):
    u = User(email=request.POST['email'], username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    u.save()
    a = Accounts(
        user=u
    )
    a.save()
```

1. Are you using django's User model?

if so you actually want this:

```
def adduser(request):
    u = User(email=request.POST['email'], username=request.POST['username'])
    u.set_password(request.POST['password'])
    u.save()
    a = Accounts(
        user=u
    )
    a.save()
```

Also, rather than using request.POST variables everywhere, have you considered using django's forms and form utilities? They're quite nice.

Comment: That seems to be 1.3 only and I was having a bunch of issues with 1.3 so I'm now using 1.2.7 :(

Comment: Nothing in Issac's answer is 1.3-only.